# Problem with letter assignment in natbib

Tags: bibliographies

I am using LyX for writing a document. I have a problem with my bibliography though:

I am using `natbib` and `plainnat` as options. But as you can see, LyX does not assign the correct letter to the date.

The entry starting with "R" should have the letter "a", the one starting with "S" the letter "b". How can I solve?

[image]

---

```
    @InCollection{carston_2012,
  author    = {Robyn Carston},
  booktitle = {The Cambridge Handbook of Pragmatics},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  title     = {{Metaphor and the literal/non-literal distinction}},
  year      = {2012},
  editor    = {Keith Allan and Kasia M. Jaszczolt},
  pages     = {469--492},
}


@Article{lewis1988a,
  author  = {David Lewis},
  journal = {Theoria},
  title   = {{Relevant Implication}},
  year    = {1988},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {161-174},
  volume  = {54},
}


@Article{1988b,
  author  = {David Lewis},
  journal = {Philosophical Papers},
  title   = {Statements Partly About Observation},
  year    = {1988},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {1--31},
  volume  = {17},
}
```

---

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}





\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[OC]{\begin{flushright}\thepage\end{flushright}}
}



\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape \nouppercase \leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape \nouppercase \rightmark}
\fancyfoot[EC]{\begin{flushleft}\thepage\end{flushleft}}
\fancyfoot[OC]{\begin{flushright}\thepage\end{flushright}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please show the underlying bib entries. Please also state (a) which one of the two entries comes first in the bib file and (b) which one is `\cite`d first in the document.

Comment: (b) "Relevant implication" is cited first in the body of the text. It also comes first in the .bib file.

Comment: Why the double {{ on one of the titles?

Comment: @daleif to be sure that lyx considers the starting capital letter of the second word "Implication".

Comment: Your write-up of what you say you're doing does *not* appear to match the screenshot you provided. For instance, the `plainnat` bibliography style does *not* truncate given names, and it places given names before surnames. In contrast, the screenshot shows "Lewis, D." in both cases. Do you maybe have more than one `\bibliographystyle` directive?

Comment: @Mico, sorry Mico, you are right. I modified the plainnat.bst file in order to put <first name, name>. But using standard plainnat does not seem to solve the issue

Comment: I think the problem might depend on the journals' names. Maybe LyX prioritizes "SPAO" because he follows the alphabetical order of the journals' names. I do not know how to change that, though

Comment: Was that the only modification you made to the bst file?

Comment: @Mico the only other changes were in some 'format.' lines of code: I just changed how the names " editors " and " pages " should be shown on the compiled pdf

Comment: Only place `{}` on the words that requires it, not the entire phrase. IMO, it should not be added here at all as it is the style that governs casing irregardless of what it said on the original publication. Of course person names and similar needs to be capitalised.

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

The following test document, which employs the information you've chosen to share so far, does *not* reproduce the issue you say you're trying to fix.

[image]

Do please look into whehter the *unmodfied* version of `plainnat.bst` that's on your system replicates the screenshot above. It it does, then the culprit has got to be with the personal changes you made to `plainnat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@Article{lewis1988a,
  author  = {David Lewis},
  journal = {Theoria},
  title   = {{Relevant Implication}},
  year    = {1988},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {161-174},
  volume  = {54},
}
@Article{lewis1988b,
  author  = {David Lewis},
  journal = {Philosophical Papers},
  title   = {Statements Partly About Observation},
  year    = {1988},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {1--31},
  volume  = {17},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the latex preambole I am using in LyX: do you think it might depend on that?

Comment: @user241423 - No, the preamble fragment you posted does not generate the problem behavior. As I wrote above: Please obtain an unmodified copy of `plainnat.bst` (from the CTAN, asy) and see if the problem persists.

Comment: plainnat gives the same problem. I tried with 'apalike' and it assigns the right letters, but I would like to stick with plainnat. Do you think it is solvable somehow?

Comment: @user241423 - As my answer demonstrates beyond the shadow of a doubt, an unmodified, unadulterated version of `plainnat` does *not* generate the problem behavior you're looking to fix. All I can suggest is that you delete (or rename...) your present copy of `plainnat.bst`, get a new, unadulterated copy from, say, https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/plainnat.bst, and perform a full recompile cycle (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more).

Comment: Ok I am trying it

Comment: I download the plainnat you linked me and used it on LyX. Still does not work, though. I do not know what the problem could be

Comment: I wonder if this could be a problm of JabRef that I am using: should I try to usa a different software to write .bib files?

Comment: @user241423 - Do you have more than one copy of `plainnat.bst` on your system? (If so, delete all copies except the one you obtained from the CTAN. Does your main tex file maybe contain more than one `\bibliographystyle` directive? What does the blg ("BibTeX log") file say about which bib style is in use? Incidentally, I can't imagine that your use of JabRef would be the source of the problem.

Comment: I deleted all the other copy but haven't solved.